# How to include JAR file in a java program that is being executed by command line (Windows)

Tags: java, jar, gson, classpath

I know that there are similar posts to this, but I tried all suggested answers there and they didn't work out (maybe I did something wrong). I have a java project with the following folders:

```
bin                                  
src
```

in the bin folder, I have few folders with .class files in them (compiled the project with eclipse, now just need to run it with command line). These are the folders inside bin:

```
client                             
game                        
protocol                                
threadPerClient                             
tokenizer
```

I also added the jar file (gson-2.2.1) to the bin folder. My main class is at threadPerClient folder, and this class name is MultipleClientProtocolServer. The main class get an int as a parameter. These are the commands that I tried to run via command line, from bin folder:

1. `java -cp gson-2.2.1.jar threadPerClient.MultipleClientProtocolServer 4000`.

And I got for that:
`Error: Could not find or load main class threadPerClient.MultipleClientProtocolServer`

2. `java -cp threadPerClient/:./ MultipleClientProtocolServer 4000`

And I got for that:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MultipleClientProtocolServer
```

3. `java -cp threadPerClient;. com.example.MultipleClientProtocolServer 4000`

And I got for that:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.MultipleClientProtocolServer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running command 1. of your question from within the bin folder. Also make sure in -cp you specify the gson jar as well as the current folder:

Unix:
java -cp gson-2.2.1.jar:./ threadPerClient.MultipleClientProtocolServer 4000

Windows should be:
java -cp gson-2.2.1.jar;. threadPerClient.MultipleClientProtocolServer 4000

but I cannot test the command for windows since I don't have a windows machine.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it from the bin folder. Also, the jar file is inside the bin folder (as I wrote in my post). But this command didn't work out

Comment: John, I edited my answer. I forgot to add the current folder in the classpath. Now it should work.